# How can I get available ApplicationDeployment Version via ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, clickonce

`CurrentVersion` and `UpdatedVersion` shows same version. As I know `UpdatedVersion` will be changed after downloading new update.
I want to check available version of application via ClickOnce before calling `ApplicationDeployment.Update()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
if (info.UpdateAvailable)
...
```

here you can see the version

```
info.AvailableVersion
```

and update size

```
info.UpdateSizeBytes
```